# Question deleted with no recourse?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have a question closed https://superuser.com/questions/831078/yosemite-osx-install-stuck-on-first-step  and a moderator comment "Don't use pirated software?" when this is not the case.

There isn't even a way to contact the moderator or another mod.

I think not having a recourse to explain the situation is a bad idea. Maybe a moderator can hold/review a question until he gets more clarification? But deleting the question directly seems a bit rude to me.

Comment: You can usually find us on [chat].

Comment: Question says you torrented the dmg. I'm currently out, and will give this a more complete answer when I get back but between that, and the lack of details, it seemed reasonable to me

Comment: Just asking, why did you torrent it? Why download a non-verified (potentially insecure or broken) copy of something you can legally download from the App Store – assuming you have a Mac? Note that if you don't have a Mac you have nowhere to install Yosemite without violating the EULA, which would in turn be considered off topic here.

Comment: @slhck I have limited connectivity, so I resolved to torrents and this seems to be quite common.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There is a lot of legit content on  torrents too. and the .app package is downloaded from the app store and I verified its signature.

Comment: Note that it's still copyright violation if you download copyrighted software from an unauthorized point of distribution, even if you have a legal license to use that software had you obtained it from the official source. Further, if your BT client is on default settings, you'll be committing further infringement by uploading parts of the file to other people. This is a much more serious crime than downloading it, but neither action is acceptable under US law, which governs any agreement with Apple.

Comment: If you have a legally licensed official Mac hardware and you have a legal license for Yosemite, either download it from Apple or it have a DVD shipped to you by Apple. Don't torrent. And if you do, don't *tell us* you did.

Answer (score 5):

The primary reason for me deleting this was that I considered it unanswerable in its current form - I figured it would be deleted anyway.

For the record, this is the question as it was

[image]

What I see?

"I'm trying to install osx yosemite from a .app package that I downloaded from a torrent."

Uh huh, outright piracy, and of course, not enough information for us to determine if his download was at fault.

"Once I reach this stage, it asks for the root password but never moves forward. Any suggestions?"

No actual attempt at troubleshooting - no error messages. No real clue for anyone what is happening.

In short, I had the option of putting on hold (And I tend to prefer this in most cases), or putting a clearly low quality question with many issues out of its misery as soon as possible.

I went with the latter. Really, 2 lines and a generic question do *not* make a quality question, and it didn't seem worth salvaging.

However, there's always a recourse.

1. Include detailed hardware and pre install software information. THIS alone might have saved the question.
2. A legitimate source so we can rule out the download being faulty. I'd probably consider leaving out the fact that its torrented, and including the fact that its been checked against the official version's hash.
3. More details on error messages - *how* dosen't it move forward? Does it beachball and go back to the same screen? Does it do nothing?
4. Once you have a question with the bare minimum of required details, flag for undeletion. We can do that.